# How to tell which dataform button ended edit when using EventToCommand

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I'm new to SilverLight and Mvvm-Light. I have a DataForm on my view that displays/edits a SelectedPerson property (a Person object) of my view model.

I want to execute a command on my viewmodel when the user clicks the Save button but don't want to take action if the user clicks cancel.

I added the following to my ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand PersonEditEnded {get; set;}
...
public void Initialize()
{
  PersonEditEnded = new RelayCommand(DoSomething);
  ...
}

public void DoSomething()
{
}
```

I added the following to my View:

```
<toolkit:DataForm x:Name="PersonForm" ... CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="EditEnded">
      <gs:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PersonEditEnded, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</toolkit:DataForm>
```

This works and the DoSomething method is being called when the user presses Submit.  However, DoSomething is also called when user presses Cancel.  Is there a way to know which button was pressed or to supress the call when Cancel is pressed?

Thanks for whatever help you can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you are looking for is hidden quite deeply into the DataFormEditEndedEventArgs, in the EditAction. This property of type DataFormEditAction can be either Commit or Cancel.

There is a way to pass the argument to the Command: Set the property PassEventArgsToCommand (on the EventToCommand object) to True. On the ViewModel, use a RelayCommand. The parameter of the delegate will be the event args, then you can do something like

```
e =>
{
    if (e.CommitAction == DataFormEditAction.Commit)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Laurent

Comment: Ok,...but if you don't pass the DataForms CurrentItem as a CommandParameter then how can you act on the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want act on the data you can also make a binding to CurrentItem and use it through your command (or elsewhere) so you can do whatever you want to the item.